# Optimality gap in DoCplex

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I've created a model in Python, **DoCplex**. After solving the model, I got a feasible solution. I'd like to get a relative and absolute optimality gaps in DoCplex. Is there a way to obtain these gaps in Docplex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find an example at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoogetsolutiononebyone.py which is part of [Making optimization simple (Python)](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)

```
sol=mdl.solve(log_output=False)
for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print("objective = ",sol.get_objective_value())
print("best bound = ",mdl.solve_details.best_bound)
print("mip gap = ",mdl.solve_details.mip_relative_gap)
```